# how to retrieve data using relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve data using relationship in laravel and I'm getting this error all the time.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.customers_id'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where
>   `orders`.`customers_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

before this I was using these codes:

```
 $data = DB::table('customers')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'customers.id')
        ->get();

    // convert to json string
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
    return $data;
```

and it return the exactly result I want which is:
[image]

**Here is my customers table:**
[image]

**orders table**
[image]

**Orders**

```
    class Orders extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class);
    }
}
```

**Customers**

```
 class Customers extends Model
{
    public function order(){
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::class);
    }
```

**DataController**

```
class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function all()
    {

        $All = Customers::with('order','order.customer_id')->paginate(10);

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 0,
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $All,
            'pagination' => [
                'current_page' => $All->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $All->lastPage(),
                'prev_page_url' => $All->previousPageUrl(),
                'next_page_url' => $All->nextPageUrl(),
                'per_page' => $All->perPage(),
                'total' => $All->total(),
                'count' => $All->count(),
            ]
        ], 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my controller

```
    $All = Customers::with('order')->paginate(10);

    return response()->json([
        'code' => 0,
        'success' => true,
        'data' =>$All

    ], 200);
```

**Customers model**

```
   class Customers extends Model
{
    public function order(){
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::class,'customer_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Orders model**

```
class Orders extends Model
{
    public function customers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class,'customer_id','id');
    }
}
```

and its works. 
But there is still got one thing which I'm not understand. Its works either I define the relationship in `Customers model` or `Orders model` or define the relationship in both

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this one

**Order Model**

```
class Orders extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

**DataController**

```
class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function all()
    {

        $All = Customers::order()->paginate(10);

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 0,
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $All,
            'pagination' => [
                'current_page' => $All->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $All->lastPage(),
                'prev_page_url' => $All->previousPageUrl(),
                'next_page_url' => $All->nextPageUrl(),
                'per_page' => $All->perPage(),
                'total' => $All->total(),
                'count' => $All->count(),
            ]
        ], 200);
```

I just put the foreign key in the model already. I'm not entirely sure if its supposed to be in `Order Model` or in `Customer Model` either way try those both.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `order.customer_id` from `Customers::with('order','order.customer_id')->paginate(10);`

So it should be

```
Customers::with('orders')->paginate(10);
```

Also as a customer can have many orders it is best to name your relation as `orders`

```
class Customers extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::class);
    }
}
```